# Google maps infowindows problems with the for()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, listener, infowindow

I'm trying to put an infowindow with different contents using a for() but it doesn't work. this my code:

```
var infowindow=[];
var myMarker=[];
var marker=[];
for (i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {
    myMarker[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(lt[i], ln[i]);
    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myMarker[i],
    map: map
  }); 
}

for (var i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {



google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],'mouseover', function(){

    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:dl[i]
    });
  infowindow[i].open(map,marker[i]);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],'mouseout',function() {
    infowindow[i].close();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],'click',function() {
    alert("Y ahora te abriría otra pagina... si tuviera una"+i);
  });


}
```

Everything is cool with the first for, but when I tried to use event listeners it goes bad.

the variables: `dl[]`, `lt[]`, `ln[]` were initialized before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infowindow doesn't work like that. Create a single copy of the infowindow (instead of maintaining an array) and set its contents with infowindow.setContent() during the mouseover event for each marker.

Edit: Your solution in your response will work, or here is a more concise solution:

```
var myMarker=[];
var marker;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {
    myMarker[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(lt[i], ln[i]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myMarker[i],
    map: map
  }); 
  (function(msg) {marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(msg);
    infoWindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    });
  })(dl[i]);
  marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! Just FYI, I saw your requested edit of Theeternalpuzzle's answer and voted to reject the edit. Instead of editing that answer to add the additional code, it would be better to add your improved code to your own answer. (And welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping your fellow developers!)

Answer (score 0):

I endend doing this, and it works very well

```
var myMarker=[];
var marker;
for (i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {
    myMarker[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(lt[i], ln[i]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myMarker[i],
    map: map
  }); 
  attachSecretMessage(marker, dl[i]);
}


function attachSecretMessage(marker, secretMessage) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: secretMessage
  });

  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);

  });

  marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  }
```